# Как выполнять простейшие арифметические действия в shell?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

Можно ли как-то сделать так (как-то настроить shell), что бы можно было в терминале набирать выражения вида `a * b`, `a + b`, `a - b`, `a / c`, где *a* и *b*- числа, и что бы это выражение вычислялось?

Т.е. что бы можно было делать вот так:

```
dzmitry@mycomp:~$ 12 * 45
```

А не запуская, например, питон:

```
dzmitry@mycomp:~$ py
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 12 * 45
540
>>>
```

Т.е. я не пользуюсь калькулятором, а использую командную оболочку с запущенным питоном, и хочу использовать командную оболочку как калькулятор, минимизируя промежуточные шаги

Comment: Запросто. `echo $((12 * 45))` или `a=$((12 * 45)); echo $a` выведет 540, можно и  с переменными -- `echo $(($a-10))` выведет 530 . Т.е. конструкция `@(( ... ))` вычисляет выражение с целыми числами в скобках прямо в шелле.

Comment: Так это более трудоемкий процесс, чем ввести _py_, нажать Enter и вычислить выражение

Comment: На самом деле  странный вопрос для времени всеобщей многооконности. Открываете еще одно окошко и вычисляете там (я обычно использую `bc` (или Emacs Lisp)). А приведенные сведения о шелле скорее применимы при написании скриптов (вместо вызова  `expr`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Можно ли как-то сделать так (как-то настроить shell)

увы, «настроить» невозможно. оболочка предназначена для выполнения команд, а не для вычисления арифметических выражений.

для таких вычислений нужна специализированная на этом программа. например (из самых распространённых) bc, dc и т.п.

**`bc`**

по умолчанию округляет результат до целых чисел. с помощью команды `scale=число` можно задать количество знаков после запятой. чтобы каждый раз не вводить эту команду, имеет смысл записать её в конфигурационный файл `~/.bcrc`.

**`dc`**

в этом калькуляторе используется [обратная польская нотация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) и, соответственно, стек. пример:

```
5 k #задать количество знаков после запятой
2 3 / p # поместить в стек 2 и 3, выполнить деление /, напечатать верхушку стека p
.66666 # это результат
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ expr 12 + 45 / 15 - 76 \* 8 + 17
-576
```

Comment: 1) Раздели таким образом, например, 60 на 32 2) Все-таки хотелось что бы не надо было вводить ничего дополнительного, кроме как выражения

Comment: ну да, целочисленно только. Sad but true. В качестве бонуса есть операция %, дающая остаток от деления